# check in assembly info in CI with tfs

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, workspace, checkin, assemblyinfo

**how i can check in assembly info in tfs?**
i am using tfs CI and i have one work space, when i try to check in pending :

> 2017-09-10T17:37:40.3410618Z No files checked in.
>   2017-09-10T17:37:40.8732772Z There are no pending changes matching the
>   specified items.

changes, tfs log show no pending change, but my dll version is right.
i can see assemblyinfo files in visual studio pending changes.
i am using assemblyinfo plugin in CI and i am check in  with powershell command:

`Tf.exe checkin $/[path]/assemblyinfo.cs`

Comment: Why do you want to commit build outputs to version control? You can publish build output with the *Publish Build Artifacts* task.

Comment: @DanielMann i Wanna check in assembly info files .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build in VS locally, the file `assemblyinfo.cs` generated within the workspace (the project in source control mapped) and will be detected automatically in Pending Changes page.

But according to your description, you build with TFS, that means the file `assemblyinfo.cs` is not in source control yet. Unless you publish/add the output to the active workspace just like build locally with VS, then you can check in directly. Otherwise you have to add the file to source control first, then check in.

So, just try to run "`tf status`" command first, it will show you list of pending changes.

```
tf stat /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/Collection
```

If that file not been listed, just run  [`tf add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/repos/tfvc/add-command?view=vsts) first, then [`tf checkin`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/checkin-command) (You need to change directory to your mapped folder first)